# Move view up/down using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification/UIKeyboardWillHideNotification when tap keyboard return key

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a `UIView` with `UITextField` that brings up a keyboard. i used `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification/UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` in Delegate method of textfield. as shown below:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

self.txtFullName.text=@"";
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

and my keyboard notification method here:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification

{

CGSize keyboardSize;
CGPoint keyboardOrigin;
CGFloat _currentKeyboardHeight = 0.0f;

NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];

keyboardSize = [[keyboardInfo    objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
keyboardOrigin = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;

CGFloat deltaHeight = keyboardSize.height - _currentKeyboardHeight;
_currentKeyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;

CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
CGFloat  statusBarHeight =   statusBarSize.height;

self.viewForSignature.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewForSignature.frame.origin.x, self.viewForSignature.frame.origin.y+statusBarHeight+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-deltaHeight, self.viewForSignature.frame.size.width, self.viewForSignature.frame.size.height);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}


-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{

CGSize keyboardSize;
CGFloat _currentKeyboardHeight = 0.0f;

NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
keyboardSize = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGFloat deltaHeight = keyboardSize.height - _currentKeyboardHeight;
_currentKeyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;

CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
CGFloat  statusBarHeight =   statusBarSize.height;

self.viewForSignature.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewForSignature.frame.origin.x,self.viewForSignature.frame.origin.y-statusBarHeight-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+deltaHeight, self.viewForSignature.frame.size.width, self.viewForSignature.frame.size.height);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

screenshot of demo given below:

[image]
[image]

move up and down  keyboard when click on return key, works perfectly. but  issue when click on textfield and sudden tap on return key the view up. as given in below scrrenshot:

[image]

what should i do? Thanks in advance

Comment: remove [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]; and  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]; from notification observer method and put it in ViewWill disappear and add it back only one in ViewWillAppear :) Try and lemme know if that solves your issue

Comment: suggestion  : It is very bad practice to add keyboard notification observer in  textfield delegate method . put your code in view did load

Comment: put all control in UIScrollView in use TPKeyboard class, it automatically manage textfield as per keyboard height.

Comment: if i used scrollview and TPKeyboard class then textfield works fine, but signature view does not work. @Jayesh

Comment: So that you need to open signature view in popup (separate) view.